# Can't hide left arrow in bootstrap carousel on load

Tags: jquery

I can't get the left arrow to hide on load, and show when the user has advanced to the second slide. The right arrow works correctly, and hides at the final slide though. When I set the left arrow to hide on load, the arrow is still visible when the user clicks back to the first slide.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
<div class="quote-carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <h6>What customers say about us</h6>
    <div class="item active">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
          <!-- <div> -->
            <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-User</span>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /Slide1 -->

    <div class="item">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
          <!-- <div> -->
            <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-User</span>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /Slide1 -->

    <div class="item">
      <ul class="thumbnails">
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
          <!-- <div> -->
            <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-User</span>
          <!-- </div> -->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /Slide1 -->


  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE314;</i>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <i class="material-icons">&#xE315;</i>
    </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
  wrap: false
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    curSlide = $('.active');
  if(curSlide.is( ':first-child' )) {
     $('.left').hide();
     return;
  } else {
     $('.left').show();
  }
  if (curSlide.is( ':last-child' )) {
     $('.right').hide();
     return;
  } else {
     $('.right').show();
  }
});
```

**JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/gusvb4zt/1/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that there is an h6 tag before your first item and that's considered as the first child so your test `curSlide.is( ':first-child' )` will never run. so u can use the css3 nth-child(2) to reference the second child which is the first item: https://jsfiddle.net/gusvb4zt/2/

Comment: Ah, forgot about `nth-child()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return the function. Also you need to run the function on load.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  wrap: false
}).on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {
  check()

});

function check() {
  curSlide = $('.active');
  if (curSlide.is(':first-child')) {
    $('.left').hide();
    $('.right').show();
  } else if (curSlide.is(':last-child')) {
    $('.right').hide();
    $('.left').show();
  } else {
    $('.left').show();
    $('.right').show();
  }
}
check()
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
    <div class="quote-carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
              <!-- <div> -->
              <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-User</span>
              <!-- </div> -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /Slide1 -->

        <div class="item">
          <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
              <!-- <div> -->
              <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-Robyn Estroff</span>
              <!-- </div> -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /Slide1 -->

        <div class="item">
          <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 slide-content">
              <!-- <div> -->
              <h3>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua, ipsum dolor amet."</h3>
              <span class="time">-Robyn Estroff</span>
              <!-- </div> -->
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /Slide1 -->


      </div>

      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE314;</i>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <i class="material-icons">&#xE315;</i>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```